# How to vertical align inside text of tableGrob R

Tags: r, gridextra

Whenever i am using tableGrob in R, i am unable to vertically align inside text of cell, column & Row, but for horizontally the option is present, core.just = "left"...

Is there anyway to vertically align the text, because it always come in centre.

Answer (score 4):

Directly adapted from the [new vignette](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob#text-justification),

```
library(gridExtra)
tt1 <- ttheme_default()
tt2 <- ttheme_default(core=list(fg_params=list(vjust=1, y=0.9)))
tt3 <- ttheme_default(core=list(fg_params=list(vjust=0, y=0.1)))

grid.arrange(
  tableGrob(mtcars[1:4, 1:3], rows=NULL, cols=NULL, theme=tt1),
  tableGrob(mtcars[1:4, 1:3], rows=NULL, cols=NULL, theme=tt2),
  tableGrob(mtcars[1:4, 1:3], rows=NULL, cols=NULL, theme=tt3),
  nrow=1)
```

[image]